# Fill multidimensional array from other array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array `$elements` where I need to fill it with values from the array `$ratings`. The array `$ratings` is built so the first value will fit into the first slot in elements, the next in the second and so on.

```
$elements
4 => array:3 [▼
  2 => 0
  3 => 0
  4 => 0
]

5 => array:3 [▼
  2 => 0
  3 => 0
  4 => 0
]

7 => array:3 [▼
  2 => 0
  3 => 0
  4 => 0
]
```

I now need to fill `$elements` with 9 specific values from

```
$ratings
array:9 [▼
0 => 3
1 => 2
2 => 1
3 => 3
4 => 3
5 => 2
6 => 3
7 => 2
8 => 1
9 => 3
]
```

If I manage to loop through `$elements`, inserting values from `$ratings` one by one, I will have solved my problem.

So `$elements[4][2]` should have the value of 3, `$elements[4][3]` should have value of 2 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$elements = [ 
    4=>[2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0],
    5=>[2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0],
    7=>[2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0],
];

$ratings = [ 0 => 3, 1 => 2, 2 => 1, 3 => 3, 4 => 3, 5 => 2, 6 => 3, 7 => 2, 8 => 1, 9 => 3 ];

$ratingsIndex = 0;
foreach(array_keys($elements) as $ElementsIndex) {
    foreach(array_keys($elements[$ElementsIndex]) as $ElementsSubIndex) {
        $elements[$ElementsIndex][$ElementsSubIndex] = $ratings[$ratingsIndex++];
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($elements);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would you do this if the keys for the $elements array can different each time? As a more dynamic solution

Answer (score 1):

Also you can manipulate these by `array_fill` using loop.

Comment: can you add more information, including an example?